# Help with Formal Proof using introduction and elimination rules

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I need help with a proof where the premise is $\lnot A \land \lnot B$ and the goal is $\lnot (A \lor B)$. We are allowed to use the introduction and elimination of the following operators: $\lnot$,$\land$,$\lor$,$=$, and $\bot$. I am having some trouble with figuring out a way to use a getting the goal from the separated steps $\lnot A$ and $\lnot B$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an example of DeMorgan's Law, and you can use a truth table to verify that $\neg (A \vee B)$ is equivalent to $\neg A \wedge \neg B$.

Comment: The approach (see answer below): assume $(A \lor B)$ and use Disjunction Elim: from every sub-proof (1st one from assumption $A$, second one from assumption $B$) derive $\bot$ (using premise) and thus conclude the $(\lor \text E)$ with $\bot$. The result follows by $(\lnot \text I)$.

Comment: Can you please specify the nature of the proof system you are supposed to use?  There are *so many* different proof systems, that are different in terms of rules and format, that a proof in one system isn't always to help you a whole lot when you're using a different system.

Answer (score 0):

See the image below (coming from a book). $\rm\vdash (\lnot A\land\lnot B)\to\lnot(A\lor B)$

$$\rm
\dfrac{\lower{1ex}{[A\lor B]^3}~~\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{[A]^4}~~\dfrac{[\lnot A\land\lnot B]^1}{\lnot A}{\small\land e}}{\bot}{\small\lnot e}~~\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{[B]^5}~~\dfrac{[\lnot A\land\lnot B]^2}{\lnot B}{\small\land e}}{\bot}{\small\lnot e}}{\dfrac{\dfrac{\bot}{\lnot(A\lor B)}{\lnot i^{3}}}{(\lnot A\land\lnot B)\to\lnot(A\lor B)}{\small{\to}i^{1,2}}}{\lor e^{4,5}}
$$

Comment: What is the picture supposed to say?

Comment: It's a formal proof in natural deduction. 'i' stands for introduction and 'e' for elimination.

Comment: Oh. That's something you would have to type as an answer rather than post a picture. Pictures containing math that can be typed in LaTeX aren't allowed, and it's better to let the OP try to figure out the problem first.

Comment: Ah OK sorry, if I had enough reputation to comment I would have, and laziness to transcript into MathJax (this one wouldn't have been simple).

Comment: I am sorry but I am having a bit of difficulty reading the picture. Is the problem broken down into 2 subproofs, and I am having understanding what rules are used.

Thanks again for the response

Comment: @MerazHossain If you're allowed to use DeMorgan's Laws, then the answer is a one-liner.

Comment: i->introduction, e->elimination, d->right, g->left. At the top you can see your premise and at the bottom, before the last applied rule (->implication) you can see your conclusion.

Comment: You haven't specified in which proof system you were. Natural deduction? Sequent calculus?